# how to modify file names in a Makefile command

Tags: makefile, rename

I'm trying to rename input->output files based on commands in a makefile.
eg 'resize', 'speedup' etc.

I can add a rename blocks at the top of the file eg to change a suffix:

```
output := $(input:.mov=.mp4)
```

but this won't work inside a make command as far as I can see

```
check:
    output := $(input:.mov=.mp4)
```

gives

```
$ input=walkthrough.mov make check
output := walkthrough.mp4
make: output: No such file or directory
make: *** [check] Error 1
```

So how would I rename files on a per make-function basis, not just once per Makefile?

---

@beta mentioned target-specific-variables but I can't seem to get that syntax working either.

```
check: output="foo"
    @echo "input ${input}"
    @echo "output ${output}"
```

errors:

```
$ input="blah" make check
Makefile:10: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Comment: It will help if you would provide short description of what you are trying to achieve - what command you want to execute for the 'check' target

Comment: I have a file with a bunch of different video processing commands, that each have a different output - change size, framerate, resolution etc. they all need a different output filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass *Make* syntax to the *shell,* the shell won't know what you're talking about.

But you can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
check: output := $(input:.mov=.mp4)
check:
    @echo $(output)
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, gives an error. is my syntax wrong? edited the question above.

Comment: @dcsan: You tried a *modified* version of my suggestion, and it didn't work. Try it verbatim.

Comment: you're right! I didn't imagine the language could require the same command name twice. :/  btw based on the comment above, I'm not actually clear where the line between make and shell syntax is.  if i can't pass `make` syntax can i pass `bash` syntax? I tried using shell in body of the command, but that also failed, eg simple substution

Answer (score 0):

Target specific variables can be set on separate line

```
check: output=$(input:.mov=.mp4)

check:
    echo input ${input}
    echo output ${output}
```

Will produce commands based on the $input

```
[owner@localhost 4]$ make input=walkthru.mov check
input walkthru.mov
output walkthru.mp4
```